# How to write my version of unfoldr in a better / more idiomatic manner in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, fold

I'm trying to write my version of `unfoldr` in order to solve a chapter exercise from [Haskell Book](http://haskellbook.com/) (Chapter 12, Signaling Adversity). The book says:

> Write the function `myUnfoldr` using direct recursion. Compare with
>   the built-in `unfoldr` to check your implementation. Again, don’t look
>   at implementations of unfoldr so that you figure it out yourself.

And gives the following:

```
myUnfoldr :: (b -> Maybe (a, b)) -> b -> [a] 
myUnfoldr = undefined
```

My initial attempt for `myUnfoldr` has been to write it using a single helper function:

```
maybeToList :: Maybe a -> [a]
maybeToList (Just x) = [x]
maybeToList Nothing = []

myUnfoldr :: (b -> Maybe (a, b)) -> b -> [a]
myUnfoldr f x = (fst $ head $ maybeToList (f x)) :
  myUnfoldr f (snd $ head $ maybeToList (f x))
```

This type checks, and for a few example runs it seems like I've achieved what `unfoldr` does, because:

```
λ> take 10 $ unfoldr (\x -> Just (x, x + 1)) 0
[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
```

and the same result with `myUnfoldr`:

```
λ> take 10 $ myUnfoldr (\x -> Just (x, x + 1)) 0
[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
```

But of course, `myUnfoldr` is problematic because if I try the following:

```
λ> take 10 $ myUnfoldr (\x -> Nothing) 0
[*** Exception: Prelude.head: empty list
```

whereas `unfoldr` works as expected, returning `[]`.

I can see why my `unFoldr` is problematic, but I couldn't find out how to handle the situation where `f` can return `Nothing`.

So my second take at the problem is to use another helper function, and this time use guards:

```
isJust :: Maybe a -> Bool
isJust (Just _) = True
isJust _      = False

myUnfoldr :: (b -> Maybe (a, b)) -> b -> [a]
myUnfoldr f x | isJust $ (f x) = (fst $ head $ maybeToList (f x)) : myUnfoldr f (snd $ head $ maybeToList (f x))
              | otherwise = []
```

This second version seems to work as expected both for `take 10 $ myUnfoldr (\x -> Just (x, x+1)) 0` and `take 10 $ myUnfoldr (\x -> Nothing) 0`

But I'm still not comfortable with my solution.

Any ideas whether it can be written in a more concise form, without using a helper function? Or in a more idiomatic way?

Comment: Yes, there is a much more straightforward way to do this, which does not involve helper functions. BTW both helper functions you defined, already exist in `Data.Maybe`, but to be clear, you can do it without them.

Comment: Small remark: since you've already solved your "problem", your question is probably eligible for [codereview.se].

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Two words: pattern matching. You're using `$ head $ maybeToList (f x)` twice to get both the next state as well as the list element. However, we can pattern match on `f x` to get whether we're having `Just` another element (and a state to continue our little unfolding) or whether we're done:

```
myUnfoldr :: (s -> Maybe (a, s)) -> s -> [a]
myUnfoldr f x = case f x of
    Just (next, state) -> next : myUnfoldr f state
    Nothing            -> []
```

The problem with your variant is that you don't use `isJust (f x)` to your advantage. Instead of checking whether something is `Just` and then getting the values out of it, just check whether the pattern matches.

Note that this is also possible with pattern guards:

```
myUnfoldr :: (s -> Maybe (a, s)) -> s -> [a]
myUnfoldr f x
  | Just (next, state) <- f x = next : myUnfoldr f state
  | otherwise                 = []
```

I haven't read the book yet, but I guess that both techniques have been told by chapter 12.

Comment: Sadly, I seem to have a mental block WRT pattern guards. I basically never think of them when writing code. I suspect this is because they weren't in Haskell 98 (the standard when I started with Haskell) and they're not as exciting/indispensable as some other extensions. Indeed, they seem to offer *reliable* performance in only a fairly narrow domain--they're great for types with at most two constructors at most one of which takes an argument, but they're otherwise less great..

Comment: @dfeuer to be honest, I usually don't use them either. I just read a comment some hours before which reminded me of them. I like the `case … of …` variant more, to be honest. `Maybe` and `Either` are probably the only things I would them for, though.